# How does the magnetic field depend on electric field in a electrostatic quadrupole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am studying a electrostatic quadrupole which is formed by four plates: two with a potential $+V_0/2$ which are parallel to each other and two with $-V_0/2$ which are parallel to each other but perpendicular to the other. According to the book that I am following the potential in that situation is

$$V(r,z) = \frac{V_0}{d^2} \; \left[(r - r_0) + z^2 \right]$$

where $r$ is the radial component used in cylindrical coordinates.

I know the electric field since I know $V(r,z)$ and it is assumed that $\pmb{B} = (0,0,B)$ where $B$ is constant and uniform. My problem is how to show that the magnetic field is precisely constant and uniform and also find and expression in function of the parameters of $V(r,z)$ since I am interested in the derivative of $\pmb{E}$ respect to $B$

Comment: There's no current and no time dependence in the electric field, at least according to the information you've given us, so why is it assumed that there is a magnetic field? If it really is an assumption from the problem statement, then why do you have to show it?

Comment: I have read the book again and it is said that the magnetic field is generated by a magnet. Can they be considered independent then? Or will they interact so $d\pmb{E}/dB \neq 0$?

Comment: In a static situation, I would assume they are independent.